# Not working custom domain - A record type azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have developed web application in VS 2015 Community Edition and deployed the same on Azure. As per instruction give [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain#map-an-a-record) I did setup A record and CName record for my site.

I have registered my domain at Godaddy and did pertaining changes as per the instructions. Some how my I am able to run the website by using www prefix e.g. www.abc.com, but withouth www prefix, its showing green page from Godaddy that this domain is parked with godaddy.

How should I resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Please add the GoDaddy and the Azure settings you used to your question, masking the sensible parts.  Without that, there's no way we can help you.

Comment: Pranay, it sounds like you added an A record for "www.pranay.org" but not for "*.pranay.org". If you want to be able to resolve http://pranay.org you need to add the latter record also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Some how my I am able to run the website by using www prefix e.g. www.abc.com, but withouth www prefix, its showing green page from Godaddy that this domain is parked with godaddy.

If I understand you correctly, you created a CNAME record to map the `www` subdomain to your web app and it could work. While the A record that maps your root domain to your web app could not work. I would recommend you check [Map an A record](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain#map-an-a-record) and make sure your configuration is correct.

Moreover, it would take some time for the changes to take effort. You could visit http://digwebinterface.com/ to check whether the DNS propagation is working as expected.

Additionally, I would recommend you map a wildcard DNS name to your web app by adding a CNAME record, then when enable your record mapping in your azure web app, you could add hostnames (e.g. `www.abc.com`, `abc.com`, `sub1.abc.com`) for your azure web app, then you could access the hostname(s) you configured. More details, you could refer to [Map a wildcard domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain#map-a-wildcard-domain).